# Parent and child for loop PHP

Tags: php, mysql

please help me create a parent and child for loop using this 3 tables coming from database. Here's my database

```
Role table

id   |   name
 1   |   Writer
 2   |   admin
 3   |   user
```

next

```
Permission Table
id     |   name
 1     |   writer.edit
 2     |   writer.create
 3     |   writer.delete
 4     |   admin.edit
 5     |   admin.create
 6     |   user.update
 7     |   user.create
 8     |   user.view
```

next is the last table that connect permission and role table

```
 Role_has_permission  table

 id    |    role_id     | permission_id
 1     |       1        |       1
 2     |       1        |       2
 3     |       1        |       3
 4     |       2        |       4
 5     |       2        |       5
 6     |       3        |       6
 7     |       3        |       7
 8     |       3        |       8
```

next the output should be...

```
writer
  -writer.edit
  -writer.create
  -writer.delete
admin
  -admin.edit
  -admin.create
user
  -user.update
  -user.create
  -user.view
```

how to loop this using PHP and mysql. its ok to put into array. as long as the output will be working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, do you have a query that selects this data?

Comment: i have 2 seperated queries. but i dont know how to display the output

Comment: I'm sorry, but Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. We can help you with specific programming problem, but this is not that. See: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Apart from that, I was wondering why your permissions table has permissions named `writer.edit` and `admin.edit`? Wouldn't just one `edit` row do? Your `Role_has_permission` table connects roles and permissions after all, so it would either connect the `writer` or the `admin` role to the `edit` permission.

Comment: Hi Kiko. there's a module that writer can only edit or delete. so that i put the writer to filter what module can the role to be access. thanks for the time. and user can add multiple roles.

Comment: user can add multiple role

Comment: Ah, OK, I understand. You've got roles, permissions, _and_ modules. The latter can only be accessed by certain roles that have certain permissions. Wouldn't it be better to actually model that in your database? So, you'll have to add a `Module` table and two connecting tables from this table to the `Role` and `Permission` table. That way you maintain a [normalized database](https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html).